# Having a main function call smaller functions?

Tags: javascript, function

I've got three separate functions for my javascript:

```
    <script>
        function validateName() {
            var x = document.forms["booking_form"]["firstname"].value;
            if (x == null || x == ""){
                alert("First name is not filled");
                return false;
            }
            var y = document.forms["booking_form"]["lastname"].value;
            if (y == null || y == ""){
                alert("Last name is not filled");
                return false;
            }
            //var z =
                }

        function validateAge(){
            if(document.booking_form.age.value < 18){
                alert("You must be at least 18 years of age");
                return false;}
                else{
                return true;}
                }


            function validateEmail(){
                if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(booking_form.email.value))  
                  {  
                    return (true)  
                  }  
                    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")  
                    return (false) 
            }
    </script>
```

How do I call these separate functions into one main function? I'm not very good with Javascript, so I'm pretty stumped :|

Comment: What have you tried so far? We cannot read your mind. We can only see what you have done, and tell you what is wrong. :)

Comment: You call a function by referencing its name and put `()` after it, like `validateEmail()`.

Comment: `document.forms` are we trying to solve this in 1998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly (let me know if I don't), it looks like you want to create a function that calls each of these individual functions and returns `true` only if all three validations succeed.
To do that, you'd simply use the `&&` operator like this:

```
function validate() {
    return validateAge() && validateName() && validateEmail();
}
```

This function will tell you if the age is valid AND the name is valid AND the email is valid.

For this to work, as [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) pointed out, you'd have to `return true` in the last line of your `validateName` function; otherwise it would return `undefined` when the validation succeeds.

Comment: This is the right approach, but note that the OP's `validateName()` doesn't ever return `true`, it returns either `false` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new function and this call others

```
<script>
    function validateName() {
        var x = document.forms["booking_form"]["firstname"].value;
        if (x == null || x == ""){
            alert("First name is not filled");
            return false;
        }
        var y = document.forms["booking_form"]["lastname"].value;
        if (y == null || y == ""){
            alert("Last name is not filled");
            return false;
        }
        //var z =
            }

    function validateAge(){
        if(document.booking_form.age.value < 18){
            alert("You must be at least 18 years of age");
            return false;}
            else{
            return true;}
            }


        function validateEmail(){
            if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(booking_form.email.value))  
              {  
                return (true)  
              }  
                alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")  
                return (false) 
        }

function globalFunction() {
   validateAge();
   validateName();
   validateEmail();
}
</script>
```

In this example, you need call a "globalFunction();"

Bye

Comment: What about the return values?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have access to the computer. I shall give that a go. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, for the return values you need `function globalFunction() {
   return validateAge() & validateName() & validateEmail();
}`